# 2-way contigency table against same variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data in which people sorted questions into groups (grouping in whatever way made sense to them). I want to count how often the same questions were put into the same group

Here is an example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(Person_ID= rep(1:3,each=3), Question_ID=rep(1:3,3),Groups=c("a","b","b","a","a","b","a","b","b"))
```

I am trying to do a form of self-contingency table or matrix, so I end up with:

```
  1 2 3 
1 2 
2 1 0
3 0 2 1
```

where both the rows and columns are the IDs of the questions. And the numbers represent how many times each pair-wise combination of questions was found in a group. The diagonals represent the number of times a question was in a group on its own.

What is the most efficient way to do this task in R, ideally in the tidyverse?

Comment: Why the tidyverse? The structure you're showing really looks like a matrix, which is not generally tidyverse (`dplyr`) material.

Comment: Your question "1" has three `a`s and zero `b`s, why the "2" in your matrix?

Comment: sure it doesnt have to be tidyverse. Any solution! I am stuck.

Comment: there is a "2" in the position for 1 against 1 because this question is put in a group on its own on two occassions

Comment: There is only one row per question per person, and question 1 is always in group "a". I don't understand how that translates into *"in a group on its own on two occasions"*.

Comment: sorry  - I know its a bit complex. Both Participant 1 and Participant 3 grouped question ID 1 on its own. the group labels (a or b) dont matter so much - it is just which question were placed in the same group or not.